# After adding data from one controller and not getting updated data in another controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[When click on Add candidate it goes to a form page after registering the candidate it again comes to same page where table shows the whole list of candidate but the newly added candidate is not shown unless I refresh the page  [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9guDN.png)

Comment: can you add related angular code ?

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution is that you need to **re-fetch** the data after new candidate is created (by AJAX call).